# Filtering Characters from a String

Tags: python, string, iteration

I need to make a function that takes two strings as imnput and returns a copy of str 1 with all characters from str2 removed.

First thing is to iterate over str1 with a for loop, then compare to str2, to accomplish subtraction I should create a 3rd string in which to store the output but I'm a little lost after that.

```
def filter_string(str1, str2):
    str3 = str1   
    for character in str1:
       if character in str2:
           str3 = str1 - str2
    return str3
```

This is what I've been playing with but I don't understand how I should proceed.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just use [`str.translate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate):

```
In [4]: 'abcdefabcd'.translate(None, 'acd')
Out[4]: 'befb'
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate):

> ```
> string.translate(s, table[, deletechars])
> ```
>
> **Delete all characters from `s` that are in `deletechars`** (if present), and then translate the characters using `table`, which must be a 256-character string giving the translation for each character value, indexed by its ordinal. **If `table` is None, then only the character deletion step is performed.**

If -- for educational purposes -- you'd like to code it up yourself, you could use something like:

```
''.join(c for c in str1 if c not in str2)
```

Comment: This works and I understand how but I don't think it was strictly how I was supposed to achieve it.

Comment: In Python3 the translate function only takes one argument, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translate#str.translate . To do the same thing in Python 3 you need to do: `'abcdefabcd'.translate(str.maketrans({'a': None, 'c': None, 'd': None}))` , see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535571/how-to-explain-the-str-maketrans-function-in-python-3-6

Comment: This is for Python2. for python3: `text = text.translate(str.maketrans('','',string.punctuation))`

Answer (score 6):

Use `replace`:

```
def filter_string(str1, str2):
    for c in str2:
        str1 = str1.replace(c, '')
    return str1
```

Or a simple list comprehension:

```
''.join(c for c in str1 if c not in str2)
```