# Getting TypeError while escaping special characters from string using Python

Tags: python, escaping

I am getting some error while escaping some special characters from string using Python. The error is given below.

Error:

```
trans_table = string.maketrans(trans_dict)
TypeError: maketrans() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Code:

```
import sys
import string
if "win" in sys.platform:
    special = """( ) < >  * ‘  = ? ; [ ] ^ ~ ! . ” % @ / \ : + , `""".split()
else:
    special = """{ }  ( ) < >  * ‘  = ? ; [ ]  $ – # ~ ! . ” %  / \ : + , `""".split()

trans_dict = {character: None for character in special}
trans_table = string.maketrans(trans_dict)
print("Lo+=r?e~~m ipsum dol;or sit!! amet, consectet..ur ad%".translate(trans_table))
```

Here I need to escape some special characters from the string.

Comment: You are using `maketrans` incorrectly. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535571/how-to-explain-the-str-maketrans-function-in-python-3-6)

Comment: I am using  `python 2.7` and can you please make this correct as per my need ?

Comment: Can you add the desired output to the question?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis : The output should be `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur ad` . Here I need to escape the given special characters from the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Python 3**

```
import sys
if "win" in sys.platform:
    special = """()<>*‘=?;[]^~!.”%@/\:+,`"""
else:
    special = """{}()<>*‘=?;[]$–#~!.”%/\:+,`"""

translator = str.maketrans('', '', special)
print("Lo+=r?e~~m ipsum dol;or sit!! amet, consectet..ur ad%".translate(translator))
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur ad
```

For more information on how the new `maketrans` works see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293875/how-to-remove-punctuation-marks-from-a-string-in-python-3-x-using-translate)

---

**Python 2**

The code given above **does not** work with Python 2. For a working solution that uses `.translate` see the answer by @Moses. I would do it like that:

```
import sys
if "win" in sys.platform:
    special = """()<>*‘=?;[]^~!.”%@/\:+,`"""
else:
    special = """{}()<>*‘=?;[]$–#~!.”%/\:+,`"""

my_string = "Lo+=r?e~~m ipsum dol;or sit!! amet, consectet..ur ad%"
my_string = ''.join(x for x in my_string if x not in special)
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur ad
```

Comment: As I am using `python 2.7`, `str` might cause error.

Comment: True, missed that.

Comment: I did as per you but still this `TypeError: maketrans() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)` error.

Answer (score 2):

`maketrans` does not take a dict in Python 2, it only takes two string parameters with equal lengths.

To delete characters you should pass a `deletechars` parameter to `translate` with a translation mapping empty strings:

```
...
delete_chars = ''.join(special)
trans_table = string.maketrans('', '')
print("Lo+=r?e~~m ipsum dol;or sit!! amet, consectet..ur ad%"
       .translate(trans_table, delete_chars))
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur ad
```

You could also drop the translation table and pass `None` to `translate`:

```
print("Lo+=r?e~~m ipsum dol;or sit!! amet, consectet..ur ad%"
  .translate(None, delete_chars))
```

Comment: How is this possible? Does this not go against the documentation?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis What documentation are you reading? [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate)?

Comment: Thanks Moses. I need some coffee! It seems you dont have to set up the table if no replacement has to be done. So, `.translate(None, delete_chars)` works too

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Ah yes, didn't see the `None` part. Thanks for the pointer.