# How to replace characters in strings without the Python re library

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am able to replace characters in strings using the Python re library, but I need to use the pyparsing library (or no library at all) instead. Is there another way to do this without re?

```
import re
string = re.sub(r'[\t\r\n]', '', string)
```

Comment: Tried chaining `replace` calls? `str.translate` can help, too.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, thanks

Comment: Essentially you'll need to design a finite state machine based on the regular expression, then go through each character of input and transition through the state machine accordingly. If the state machine is in a valid state after the final character is processed, the expression matches. Please consider if you actually want to process a regular expression or string replacements.

Comment: You can use `str.maketrans` and `str.translate` to remove all these characters at once.  See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535571/how-to-explain-the-str-maketrans-function-in-python-3-6/41536036#41536036) for the ways to create a translation table.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string = "".join(string.splitlines()).replace('\t', '')
```