# I want to delete vowels from a word in python,

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

if input is '`ameer bau'`  then output should be `'mr b'`  but i am getting error `'index out of range'`  my code is below

```
str=input()
new=list(str)

for i in range(len(new)):
    if new[i]=='a' or new[i]=='e' or new[i]=='i' or new[i]=='o' or new[i]=='u':
        new.pop(i)

str1="".join(new)
print(str1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: The three rules of writing small programs: 1. Debug 2. Debug 3. Debug https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = 'ameer bau'
new_string = ''

for letter in string:
    if letter not in 'aeiou':
        new_string += letter

print (new_string) 
# mr b
```

To change it to exactly fit your question:

```
string = input('Enter your string here: ')
new_string = ''

for letter in string:
    if letter not in 'aeiou':
        new_string += letter

print (new_string) 
# mr b
```

Also, `str` is a reserved keyword, you should not use it as a variable name

Comment: Why are you using `_` as a loop variable if you're referencing it elsewhere?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I do not understand your question. Please clarify

Comment: `_` is usually used to indicate that you don't care about the value of an expression, but Python requires you to assign it. For readability, you should give the loop variable a meaningful name.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh That's an interesting convention. Could you point me in the way of documentation for it. Also, can you give an example of a correct code usage of what you just mentioned. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python) covers all the bases.  The general use cases are things like `foo, _ = returns_tuple()` and `[[] for _ in range(5)]`

Comment: Thanks Patrick! I learnt something new myself too. I'll edit the answer to address this concern.

Answer (score 3):

In your `for` loop you iterate over the indices of `new`, however in the body of the loop `new.pop(i)` is called. That changes the size of the list eventually causing the `IndexError`.

Instead, use a list comprehension (if you need the list) or a generator expression:

```
string = input()
vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}
new_string = ''.join(x for x in string if x not in vowels)
print(new_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to [build a translation table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535571/how-to-explain-the-str-maketrans-function-in-python-3-6/41536036#41536036) then use `str.translate` to discard the vowels:

```
remove_vowels = str.maketrans('', '', 'aeiou')

'example text'.translate(remove_vowels)
# 'xmpl txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

Everytime an item is popped from `new`, the list gets shorter, thus leading to an index error. You could instead do:

**Edit:** like @Rarblack pointed out, this does not work on strings with more than one vowel directly in a row. Sorry for that.

```
for i in new:
    if i in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'):
        new.remove(i)

str1 = ''.join(new)
```

Comment: damn, you're right... I'm sorry, tested it with the wrong example. This will only work on strings that have no more than one vowel in a row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.translate` or a regular expression, i.e.

```
new.translate(str.maketrans('','','aeiou'))
```

where `str` is the string keyword and not your variable name, or you could do

```
import re
new = re.sub('[aeiou]','',input())
```