# remove special character from string in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, special-characters

Like i have string variable which has value is given below

```
string_value = 'hello ' how ' are - you ? and/ nice to % meet # you'
```

Expected result:

hello how are you and nice to meet you

Comment: You can use the same technique as this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173555/filtering-characters-from-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try just removing all non word characters:

```
string_value = "hello ' how ' are - you ? and/ nice to % meet # you"
output = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', re.sub(r'[^\w\s]+', '', string_value))
print(string_value)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
hello ' how ' are - you ? and/ nice to % meet # you
hello how are you and nice to meet you
```

The solution I used first targets all non word characters (except whitespace) using the pattern `[^\w\s]+`.  But, there is then the chance that clusters of two or more spaces might be left behind.  So, we make a second call to `re.sub` to remove extra whitespace.

Comment: For those who don't read RegEx like English, the key function here is documented at https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.sub, and RegEx as used in Python is documented at https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp